# Getting a forwarded URL from thousands of different domains in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, forwarding

I actually asked this question before, but I cannot get my account details back, so I'm asking again:

I have a series of different domain names that I would like to all point (via URL forwarding from my domain host) to a google app engine application that reads what the forwarding URL is. So if the domain typed in was original XYZ.com, then when I am forwarded to my application, I can return what that original domain name was. I'm using the python variant. How best can I do this without coding for each and every variant?

So for example I might have aaa.com and bbb.com and ccc.com that all should point to the same appspotdomain, and I wish to somehow determine what the referring URL was. I have thousands of domains and I have URL forwarding set-up. So unless I put something in the header is there a smart way to pull out the referring URL. I have tried the os.environ["SERVER_NAME"] route but this just gives the app-engine domain.

Comment: _Thousands_ of domains? What on earth are you doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
os.environ['HTTP_REFERER']
```

or

```
self.request.headers['Referer']
```

Be careful though, it might not always be available.